# Should I prefix my setter method with "set" if it does something more than just setting a value?

Tags: java, methods, naming-conventions

For example I have a simple POJO class with some properties. What more my setters are doing is notifying the property change listener in my class to fire a property change event. Are they setters or not in this context? Should I name them something else or adding this comment suffices? Some sample code:

```
/**
 * This is a special setter which uses property change support.
 * @param engineerOnDue engineer
 */
public void setEngineerOnDue(String engineerOnDue) {
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("engineerOnDue", this.engineerOnDue, this.engineerOnDue = engineerOnDue);
}
```

Comment: I don't see why that couldn't be known as a setter.

Comment: This is just an example. What I'm talking about is a method which not only sets a value but does something else too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the API you wish to provide to your client. Normally the client doesn't need to know the implementation of the method, so if the set-name covers the bandwagon: just use it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides encapsulation, this is the main reason why JavaBeans setters are used: to be able to fire an event each time a property changes. This definitely should be a setter.

Read the [Java tutorial about JavaBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html). What you went to do is define a *bound property* in your bean.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's still a setter.  The whole benefit of using getter/setter methods over public fields is that they allow you to do more than just set a field.  It also hides the internals from the callers of the class, allowing you to change the functionality as often as you like without worry about breaking the other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you and your team are happy with that, leave it so. I would create two methods, a simple setter and the other that sets the property (which calls the setter anyhow). Unless you can't split the operations because they must be issued together.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a POJO just a container to store values with no logic in it? Maybe you should fire that event from your use case, not from the POJO...

Than you even don't have to think about if this setter should be called a setter.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the whole point of using getters/setters instead of public methods is to allow you to do things when properties are changed. So go on. I wouldn't even tell the client I'm doing something else there, it is not his businesses to know so.
But please NEVER to time consuming tasks (database checking, network access) there: The user will have a reasonable expectancy for a setter to be fast.